# How to show hidden content by pressing tag <a> using selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an .content with 'many' div's inside:

```
<div class="content">

<div class="news">
   <a class="show_more" href="#">show news 1</a>
    <div class="hidden">
        <p>some news 1</p>
        <a class="close_hidden" href="#">close</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="news">
   <a class="show_more" href="#">show news 2</a>
    <div class="hidden">
        <p>some news 2</p>
        <a class="close_hidden" href="#">close</a>
    </div>
</div>
...
<div class="news">
   <a class="show_more" href="#">show news n</a>
    <div class="hidden">
        <p>some news n</p>
        <a class="close_hidden" href="#">close</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

simple css: `.hidden{display:none;}`

and jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.show_more').click(function(){
    $('.hidden').slideDown();
});
$('.close_hidden').click(function(){
    $('.hidden').slideUp();
});});
```

For obvious reasons, my code opens all the hidden divs, even when I click only one `<a>`.

How to show hidden content by  using $(this) or something similar?

I know it's possible by using `<a>` id (adding to .class name id of tag `<a>`):

```
 $('.show_more').click(function () {
            $('.' + this.id).slideDown();
    });
```

But when I have for example 100 divs, it's not practical to identify each `<a>` with an id and put in .hidden class this id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can use `parent()` and `children()` to do that.

Here is an example:

```
$('.show_more').click(function(){
   $(this).parent().children('.hidden').slideDown();
});
```

Comment: Work great for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can traverse the DOM (starting from the clicked element) to find the correct hidden element.

```
$('.show_more').click(function(){
   $(this).closest('.news').find('.hidden').slideDown();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! What I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your html the element you are showing/hiding is the next element so [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) is probably your best option  -

```
$('.show_more').click(function(){
  if ($(this).next("div.hidden:visible").length == 0)
    $(this).next("div.hidden").slideDown();
  else
    $(this).next("div.hidden").slideUp ();
});
```